# Translate symfony 2 entity form values

Tags: php, forms, symfony, internationalization

I need to translate the values for an entity in a choice field in my symfony 2 form. I know that normal choice fields are translated automatically. But I want to translate the choices that come from an entity I specified like this:

```
$builder->add('status', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Status',
    'translation_domain' => 'AcmeDemoBundle'
));
```

Lets say I have an entity which will give back a value of `old status` which I implemented with the `__toString` function. According to this messages file it should give me `new status` in the choice list which is generated in my form.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
                <source>old status</source>
                <target>new status</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

My question is: Is this even possible? If yes what am I missing?

Hint: Translations work if I just translate a single text in twig for example.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Symfony 2.1.x? translation_domain was not present in Symfony 2.0.x.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. There is no error displayed and if I change the property to something that does not exist symfony directly shows an error.

Comment: Using the same entity in another form type without the translation_domain worked perfectly. I removed the property from the original type and there it works now too. So it seems, that I just misspelled the domain.

Answer (score 0):

For symfony 2.7+ you have to enable it. See http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-form-and-validator-updates#added-choice-translation-domain-domain-to-avoid-translating-options.